# Mysql - Get count of unique distinct ip for each hour, each day

Tags: mysql, distinct

An updated question to ask:
I have a table with date and ip. I want to pull the count of new non-repetitive distinct ips for each hour, instead of the count of distinct ip aggregated hour

My table looks like

```
Date          Time              IP
07-01-2018  08:00:00           1.1.1
07-02-2018  09:00:00           1.1.1
07-02-2018  10:00:00           2.2.2
07-03-2018  11:00:00           1.1.1
07-03-2018  12:00:00           2.2.2
07-03-2018  13:00:00           3.3.3
```

Then on

```
07-01-2018 08:00:00, distinct count of ip should be 1 (1.1.1)
07-02-2018 09:00:00, new distinct count of ip should be 0
07-02-2018 10:00:00, new distinct count of ip should be 1 (2.2.2) 
07-03-2018 11:00:00, new distinct count of ip should be 0
07-03-2018 12:00:00, new distinct count of ip should be 0
07-03-2018 13:00:00, new distinct count of ip should be 1 (3.3.3)
```

The result I expect to be:
Date         Hour     Counts
07-01-2018 08:00:00   1 
07-02-2018 09:00:00   0
07-02-2018 10:00:00   1 
07-03-2018 11:00:00   0
07-03-2018 12:00:00   0
07-03-2018 13:00:00   1

Vlam's query works for unique counts by each day,
    SELECT aa.date, count(distinct aa.ip) as count_ips FROM table1 aa
where not exists
(select bb.ip from table1 bb where bb.ip = aa.ip and bb.date < aa.date)
group by aa.date order by aa.date asc;

Now I would like to break down to each hour. Any advice?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified the original SQL and just added a filtering to remove any IP addresses that have appeared before the date in the row since only NEW IP addresses should be counted.

```
SELECT aa.date, count(distinct aa.ip) as count_ips FROM table1 aa
where not exists
(select bb.ip from table1 bb where bb.ip = aa.ip and bb.date < aa.date)
group by aa.date order by aa.date asc;
```

Comment: Vlam, thank you so much for your answer again. I just posted a new question of which I would like to break down unique counts by each hour. Could you shed some lights on?